# cronjob wait issue

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

i am running python scripts on a ubuntu server though cronjob bellow is my bash file content

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
nohup scrapy crawl first_job &
nohup scrapy crawl second_job &
nohup scrapy crawl third_job &
wait $(pgrep third_job)
nohup scrapy crawl fourth_job &
```

what i want is **fourth_job** start executing as soon as **third_job** complete

but

currently even if **third_job** complete , **fouth_job** wait for the completion of **first_job** and **second_job**

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure `pgrep third_job` is only returning the _pid_ for `third_job` and not the _pids_ of all three jobs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Safer way to get a PID of the last background process is to remember the value of $!:

```
nohup scrapy crawl third_job &
PID=$!
wait $PID
```

Comment: thanks for an answer what if i like to wait for second_job , like if second_job end , fourth get started , no matter 1,3 are completed or still running ?

Comment: @akhterwahab: Just put the line `PID=$!` immediately after the start of the job you want to wait for.